# Android - Push Notification by battery percentage without launching the app

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am trying to build a function that takes pushes notification based on the battery percentage.

Scenario 1:
The battery percentage dropped in between a range of 30% to 40% and the notification will pops out in the notification bar with some message, telling them (by notification) the user is low on battery charge.

I have tried to do a service but to no avail. I was able to get BroadcastReceiver to retrieve the battery percentage and pops up the notification but i just can't get the service to work out.

I got two classes, MainActivity and BatteryService

This is what i put in my BatteryService class

```
public class BatteryService extends Service {

int level;
public BroadcastReceiver BatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

        if (level == 50)
        {
            // Notify the user with notification
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerReceiver(this.BatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Command=" + level + "%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(BatInfoReceiver);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I got errors like

```
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in app.bayer.notificationbattery.BatteryService$1@414bc4d8
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at app.bayer.notificationbattery.BatteryService$1.onReceive(BatteryService.java:25)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
07-29 03:08:49.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     ... 9 more
```

Am i doing my service or broadcastReceiver wrongly?

EDIT:
The method i placed in MainActivity to make the notification.

```
public void buildNotification(Context context){
      NotificationManager notificationManager 
      = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

      builder
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.boostninja)
          .setContentTitle("Berocca Performance")
          .setContentText("Locate our store to charge your phone")
          .setTicker("Berocca Performance")
          .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500) //setLights (int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
          .setAutoCancel(true);

      Notification notification = builder.build();
      notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notification);
 }
```

Comment: Ahh i just realized i made a mistake on this line
I was calling my method in the MainActivity which is buildNotification(Context context) and i called it in BatteryService with mainactivity.buildnotification(mainactivity) where MainActivity mainactivity. How do i correct it?

Comment: You should never create objects of Activities in order to access their methods. Create a Utils class, take the code out of your Activity and place it in there.

Comment: I am kinda new to utils. how do u go about doing it?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant method you want to access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `buildNotification` method inside a new class. Let's say, you call it 'Utils'.

```
public class Utils {

public void buildNotification(Context context){...}

}
```

Now call it like this from the service and from your original Activity you extracted it from:

```
Utils utils = new Utils();
utils.buildNotification(<context argument goes in here>);
```

Now you have refactored it out of the Activity and don't have to create an object of the Activity in order to access it.